# How to update D3 scatterplot dat from csv with dropdown?

Tags: d3.js

I created a d3 scatterplot from a csv and now I want to use a dropdown to updae what data is displayed from the csv. Here is a plunk of what I have so far:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NNDlG0KBcvpTfKWK6ToB?p=preview

I found this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848 but am confused on how the csv data is being loaded

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, states) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var stateById = d3.map();
  states.forEach(function(d) { stateById.set(d.id, d); });
  dispatch.load(stateById);
  dispatch.statechange(stateById.get("CA"));
});
```

and the use of the dispatch events

```
dispatch.on()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The dispatch object is documented [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals) and yes, it's takes a bit of intense-ish frowning to figure out what it does but its nice to use once you do.  What don't you understand about loading the [d3.csv](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV)?

Answer (score 0):

[d3.csv](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) simply loads a file from the provided URI (a local file called data.csv in your exampample) and calls back the function passed to it with the csv data in the second argument of the callback.  Then you can do all your data work inside the callback context.

[d3.dispatch](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals) is a wonderful little tool that makes asynchronous programing very easy.  It's just an object that contains custom events specified by the host code and provides interfaces for triggering them and managing the listeners.

For example, you can do this...
    // create the dispatch object and specify the events
    var disp = d3.dispatch("e1", "e2");

```
// add listeners with namespacing
disp.on("e1.namespace1", function(p){alert("e1 " + p)})
    .on("e2.namespace1", function(p){alert("e2 ns1 " + p)})
    .on("e2.namespace2", function(p){alert("e2 ns2 " + p)});

// then later you can trigger the events
disp.e1("triggered");
disp.e2("triggered");

// then, when your tired of playing with them, you can delete listeners
disp.on(e1, null);
```

and that's all there is to it.